# Open Source XML Firewalls?

Tags: security, firewall, xml, web, web-services

Does anyone know of any open source XML firewalls that provide equivalent functionality to DataPower, Vordel, etc?

Comment: I don't need it for implementation but am simply interested in seeing code for how they are developed.

Comment: Out of interest: XML Firewall? Do you mean configuring a (conventional) firewall by using XML, or do you mean something that does content inspection and accepts/denies depending on the (XML) content of the request?

Answer (score 1):

I'll second Josh's recommendation on ModSecurity.  If your XML data is being served/processed via Apache, either directly or proxied through it, then I would give it a shot.  It will take a fair amount of tuning and your will have to roll up your sleeves.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to AccessStream "Open Source Enterprise Application Security" ?